# Magento 1.9 Transactional Email 'Add New Template' Page Error

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I've recently upgraded from Magento 1.7 to 1.9. Everything appears to work fine except one thing. When I try to create email template from `System > Transnational Emails > Add New Template`, the page does not load entirely. When I check the code, I see the following fatal error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Newaccountnotify_Helper_Data' not found in /home2/mycpaneluser/public_html/mywebsite.com/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

[image: Here's the screenshot of the page with error:]

EDIT: Looks like I sorted this out finally. It may not be ideal but work for me now. I created a folder called 'Newaccountnotify' under app/code/core/Mage. Under it I created the following folder & file: /Helper/Data.php. Then the following code is placed in the Data.php file:

```
class Mage_Newaccountnotify_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data { }
```

Now my add new template page is loading just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your config.xml is lacking a `<helpers>` node inside of `global`, it should look like this:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <text_before_slash>Prefix_Of_Helper</text_before_slash>
        <helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

So I assume something like:

```
<newaccountnotify>Company_Newaccountnotify_Helper</newaccountnotify>
```

Comment: Just checked the system.log, which has the following error:

Warning: include(Mage/Newaccountnotify/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home2/mycpusername/public_html/mysite.co.uk/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Any clue?

Comment: You already wrote this in your question. It is helpful if you paste the config.xml of the `Newaccountnotify` module

Comment: Well, I don't see any 'Newaccountnotify' folder. Not in under Mage/ or any other folder. :(

Comment: `grep` is your friend

Comment: double checked, using the grape command. But there is no module or called 'Newaccountnotify' in the entire magento directory. I also checked the old magento 1.7 site from where I upgraded, it's not there too. Any idea what could went wrong?

Comment: I assume something want to translate in the context of the module `Newaccountnotify`, therefore it comes from somewhere. When it is not in the files, it is in the database.  The helper is used, so it is called somewhere.

Comment: Just checked the database thoroughly. No instance of 'Newaccountnotify' either in the database. Is there any other way I can bypass this?

Comment: scopp22 your magento is a closed system, the string has to come from somewhere, either from the files or the database. Maybe you have an encrypted module. But it comes from somewhere.